# YouTube instantly pauses itself when I unpause, but only sometimes

Tags: youtube, video, video-streaming

If I click the Play button, it just instantly pauses itself again.

If I hold "K", the video plays at a little over 50% speed due to constantly switching between paused and unpaused. The pop-up bubble in the center always pops up with the Play symbol.

[Video of the problem happening.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akZCk0CnxKk)

This problem only occurs sometimes. Reloading the page fixes the problem most of the time. But it's very annoying and I'd prefer to prevent it from happening.

My system info: Xubuntu 18.04 64-bit, Firefox 61.0.1 64-bit, GTX 770 GPU.